# Joomla 3 + jPeople template only showing text after “Read More” and showing it double

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

I've installed the latest Joomla + [jPeople template](http://www.freshjoomlatemplates.com/free-joomla-3-5-template-jpeople/). Nothing else. No sample data or other other templates / modules etc.

I've created 1 article:
[image: Article inside Admin Panel]

I've created a simple Menu item towards this article, with the following result:
[image: End result on website]

As you can see, the part above the "Read More..." is not shown at all. This might be the way it's supposed to be. Not sure about that. But it's also showing the part underneath it twice. I thought this might have something to do with caching, but that template has no caching settings and Joomla's cache is also empty. So I'm a bit out of ideas on what's going on and how to fix both issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the template was fake. Or at least tempered with.

Inside "*jPeople/html/com_content/article/default.php*" on line 156:

```
if (($current_id == $ids[4]) && ($count_array >= 5 )) {
    $para_array = explode(' ', $item_text);
    $item_text = preg_replace('/' . $para_array[37] . '/','<a id="main-article" href="http://www.americanbinaryoptions.com/">' . $para_array[37] . '</a>',$item_text, 1);
    echo $item_text;
} else {
    echo $item_text;
}
```

And on line 194:

```
<?php echo $this->item->text; ?>
```

So it was echoing the articles text twice with the first echo trying to replace the article with spam.

Comment: Geez, I almost want to download that template just so that I can review the code! I have concerns about that first snippet, and if that's what just 7 lines look like, there will likely be more to critique.  ...not confidence inspiring.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've given up on Joomla long time ago. It's great for small and midsized companies that need a website which is update-able by their staff without technical knowledge, but as a professional it's much easier to develop everything yourself from the ground up. Saved me a lot of headages like this.